# "that" meaning in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> Busy waiting wastes CPU cycles that some other process might be
> able to use productively

Does it mean some other process might not be able to be used productively?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should parse it as *...that some other process **might have been able** to use productively.* The cpu cycles ***are*** being wasted by "busy waiting", so they're not *actually* available to be used by another process (that ***could have*** used them if they ***had*** been available). And (completely optional) ***that*** is simply a syntactic "placemarker" for aforementioned  ***CPU cycles***.

Comment: "That" has no meaning here whatsoever. It's a meaningless subordinator functioning as a marker for the relative clause "that some other process might be able to use productively". In your example, it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

*that* is a **relativiser**.  It introduces the relative clause *some other process might be able to use productively*.  The clause modifies *cycle*.

As CPU cycles are wasted, those other processes are hence not used productively.

Comment: Thanks,I understand now.The CPU cycles that some other process are running are wasted.

Comment: It's not the processes that aren't used productively. The sentence says that the processes can't use the CPU cycles productively because those cycles are wasted due to busy waiting.

Answer (score 0):

> *Busy waiting wastes CPU cycles* [*that some other process might be able*
> *to use ___ productively*].

"That" is a subordinator introducing the bracketed relative clause. Subordinators have no meaning; they simply introduce a clause and are often omissible.

The relative clause contains a gap "____" in the position if object of the verb "use", and this gap is linked to the nominal "CPU cycles" (the antecedent).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It's not talking about whether the PROCESS is used productively, but whether CPU CYCLES are used productively. Those are two very different ideas. The computer might divide CPU cycles between processes in some very inefficient manner, but users still manage to use all the applications very productively.

The sentence is saying that in certain conditions CPU cycles are wasted that could have been used to do useful work by some "productive" process, rather than a "waiting" process. Like, if you had a sales clerk whose job is presumably to help customers, but for whatever reason the clerk has to wait for a particular customer to want help, then the clerk is wasting time that could have been used to help other customers.